# Rendering freemarker Chunks in java

Tags: java, templates, freemarker

I have created a freemarker template in which I like to display 2items per row in html. 
**example**: if I have 4items
I like to display 2 items/row. I have done this using **Chunks** of freemarker.

But my problem is, I like to do a conditional check before I render the list,but not able to access "**cell**" value directl, when I using it is throwing following error:

*freemarker.log.JDK14LoggerFactory$JDK14Logger error
SEVERE: 
Expected hash. cell evaluated instead to freemarker.core.SequenceBuiltins$chunkBI$ChunkedSequence$1 on line 4, column 22 in shoppingPromo.ftl.

### The problematic instruction:

==> if cell.promoURL?? [on line 4, column 17 in shoppingPromo.ftl]
*

**My Template**

```
<table width="312" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
                 <!-- list1-->
        <#list renderList?chunk(2) as cell>
        <!-- wanted to check if cell.item is empty here -->
                <!-- something like this <#if cell.promoURL??> -->
        <tr>
                     <!-- list2-->
            <#list cell as keys>
                <td>test</td>
            </#list>
        </tr>
        </#list>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I sense some confusion here. `?chunk(2)` gives you a list of lists. One list per chunk, each contains 1 or 2 items in your case. So which of the up to 2 cell items do you want to check?

Comment: i like to check both the list to verify it contains "null" values for  "cell.promoURL" item.

Comment: Then that's `cell[0].promoUrl?? || (cell[1].promoUrl)??`